# Textbook reference for a first course in Harmonic Analysis/Fourier Series

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Just looking for any recommendations. My background includes Graduate level Complex Analysis, Measure Theory, Topology, and Multivariable Real Analysis. I will be taking a course on Analysis on Manifolds and Differential Geometry in the near future.

Comment: [Stein and Shakarchi](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691113845/fourier-analysis)

Comment: Impressive CV. Given that CV though the question itself makes you appear slightly lazy. What are your own initial thoughts regarding the context and place of Harmonic Analysis/Fourier Analysis in the pantheon of mathematics? I often find thinking for yourself before the indoctrination formally begins is very helpful.

Comment: Thinking for yourself? That sounds dangerous...

Comment: @AdamRubinson: You remind me of the fact that mathematicians were historically hooked on Ptolemaic System of astronomy (which is after all is just a basic form of harmonic analysis) for over a thousand years and by the end thinking anew did become very dangerous e.g. for the likes of Galileo who took Copernicus' heliocentric system seriously.

Comment: I asked my topology prof. if the universe was open or closed, he said it was heresy asking him that

Comment: Wish me luck gents, I decided to take the course in the end. I'm hoping to dive into PDE's from a more rigorous perspective, so here we go. I took Measure Theory using the text written by Stein and Shakarchi so If it's anything like the problems in the Real Analysis text then I'm in all in.

Comment: @JamesArathoon, why you think I'm lazy? It's always pressed upon us that seeking out answers is a sign of strength and to ask questions even if you're lost. Most of my peers know very little on the vast subjects that are out there, I was surprised some don't even know about General Relativity and Einstein. Some are just going with the flow.

Comment: But yes, Fourier Analysis has wide applications, especially in math physics, so fits my calling. I find it as necessary as a course on Differential Geometry.

Comment: No harm meant. To explain my view more clearly.  Perhaps you could have shown more evidence of self-motivation/self-study in your question - evidence you had conducted at least one web search would have helped for example. Also someone who has reached your attainment level in maths might be expected to give a few answers back to the community over time, not just ask questions.  A good maths education is supposed to boost your confidence to tackle new unfamiliar problems and other peoples questions not hinder it.

Comment: By the way I a 55 year old engineer, so your already a way better mathematician than me. I might ask a question on an uncompleted derivation in mathematical physics I made in my 1991 undergraduate dissertation to ask if you or others can help me apply Fourier analysis to give a better solution.